# Error: No variants found for ':expo-gl-cpp' in react-native android buid

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo

I am getting an error when I try to run react-native android build in android studio.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZVn1.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwymI.png)